# Cannot set resolution above 1920x1080

Tags: resolution, windows-11, display-settings

I'm trying to increase my resolution from 1920 x 1080 to 3840 x 2160 on Windows 11.

I have an Intel® Core™ i5-12400 Processor with Intel(R) UHD Graphics 730 with the latest drivers, 31.0.101.3790. [This should be able to support higher resolutions][1]

My monitor is a Phillips PHL BDM4350 connected by HDMI

In the Intel Graphics Command Centre I can see 3840 x 2160 is listed as supported, but there is no option to select it. When I add it as a custom resolution and try to choose it the change is ignored.

Can anyone advise me?
[1]: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/134586/intel-core-i512400-processor-18m-cache-up-to-4-40-ghz.html

Comment: Are you using a 4k rated HDMI cable?

Comment: Try a DP cable if available, also make sure the monitor supports that kind of resolution over HDMI (I had this issue with a Dell monitor once).